# Why add views/album/album/ why creating another album folder inside the first one?

Tags: zend-framework2

In the zend framework tutorial album application on Zend feamework official website,

Why when creating views, we have to create views/album/album/files
and not making it : views/album/files

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the view paths (detailed [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html#initialise-the-view-scripts)), by default the view renderer looks for views at `<module>/<controller>/<action>`. So if you're viewing the 'files' action from the 'album' controller within the 'album' module, that's how you get `view/album/album/files`.